# What is the distribution of $1_A(X)$ if A is the event X>n

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

So I have been stumped with this problem for a while, I know that the mean of the indicator function is just $P(A)$ and that it has variance $P(A)^2-P(A)$, so that's a strong indicator that it has a Bernoulli distribution with $P(A)$ as a parameter, so far so good.

Now the question is, what happens is $A= {X>n}$ for X nonzero, I have two guesses, the first one I'm pretty sure is incorrect, that is it would have Bernoulli distribution with probability 1/2, because it is greater than x or not, this would not reflect the actual value of n.

Second guess is to use the complementary distribution, How many ways can X be less than n if n is 4? 5 ways, 0,1,2,3,4. 5 divided by the total ways of picking a number, which is infinity, so I'm not sure either.

Could you help me out?

Edit: the question does not say what kind of distribution X has.

Answer (score 1):

To find the distribution we simply note that an indicator is either equal to $0$ or $1$. Also, from the definition of an indicator, $P(\mathbf{1}_A = 1) = P(A)$. Thus, $\mathbf{1}_A$ is a Bernoulli random variable with parameter $p=P(A)$. Without knowing more about $X$, we cannot know the exact value of $p$.

Comment: Thank you, I thought as much, but wasn't sure.